# Css style table:hover does not work when background image set from js.

Tags: html, css

I have one div and I have added list of tables to it, to create menu effect and I have set background for each table using CSS Style as follows:

```
table
{
  background: url('normal.png') no-repeat right top;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

I am changing background image of the table on Hover event as follows:

```
table:hover
{
  background: url('hover.png') no-repeat right top;
}
```

What I want to do is, when user clicks on one of the table, I want to display some different bg image and it should remain there until user selects another table from the list.

how to archive it in CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using
`table:visited { }` and `table:active { }`

Comment: I dnt understand what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Try to achieve an Menu navigation using HTML Tables and CSS. user can use this menu to navigate.

Comment: You'll need to use some JavaScript in any case. Show some HTML. Why are you using tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this using just CSS.

I would try using jQuery to add and remove a class to the tables.